# Unable to set breakpoints in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

When I use chrome developer tools to set a breakpoint it wont set it exactly in the line that I wanted to be set. It changes it to another line. Why this happens? and what should I do if i want to set a breakpoint in the line i want?

here is the video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7NuLgKMVzkgUHhaclM0YW1BSEU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger allows you to add breakpoints on **statements**. This is achieved by clicking on the line number where the statement begins. You can't add a breakpoint on an expression within.

### Example

The following code is a mockup of the Angular code in your video:

```
$stateProvider.state("key1", {
    url: "url1",
    controller: "controller1",
    templateUrl: "templateUrl1"
}).state("key2", {
    url: "url2",
    controller: "controller2",
    templateUrl: "templateUrl2"
});
```

There is only **one** statement, beginning on line 1 and ending on line 9. You may be calling two functions that chain together, but they are one statement.

### Injecting debugger/trace statements

You can work around this restriction by adding a `debugger` statement into the `state` function, so that it breaks for every chained function call. You can run something like into the Console/Snippet:

```
var oldState = $stateProvider.state;

$stateProvider.state = function() {
    debugger;
    return oldState.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This saves a reference to the old function definition, and then overwrites the current with the `debugger` statement. If you didn't care about the real functionality, you could end it there. However, to continue normal execution, we can call the origin function using `apply`, which specifies the context and the arguments to be passed in. You can read a detailed explanation [here](https://gideonpyzer.com/blog/debugging-javascript-by-redefining-functions/).

Now this will break for every `state` execution. What if you just wanted to break for a particular case? Well you could add a [Conditional Breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en#create-conditional-breakpoints) on the `debugger` statement as per below:

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

Now the code will only break when the `key` is 'key2'.

A debugger statement can be intrusive on your execution flow, so you could replace it with a `console.log` statement, or anything else. The conditional logic could be omitted in this case.